# How do I convert MAC address to formatted MAC address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Input: 009CFAEEB779

Output:00:9C:FA:EE:B7:79

I was searching for the method but didn't find. Is there any method? or I need to loop(map) through it and add the colon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do more research before posting on SO and don't include Rails tags unless the problem relates to web programming using Rails methods.

```
arr = "009CFAEEB779".scan(/\w{2}/)
=> ["00", "9C", "FA", "EE", "B7", "79"]
arr.join(':')
=> "00:9C:FA:EE:B7:79"
```

or shorter

```
"009CFAEEB779".scan(/\w{2}/).join(':')
=> "00:9C:FA:EE:B7:79"
```